# New DSE Cassandra cluster system.hints missing

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, datastax-enterprise, cqlsh

I recently installed DSE through LCM . Was just looking at internal keyspace and saw system.hints is missing in the list.

Is it created internally in case of first node failure ?

```
select table_name from system_schema.tables where keyspace_name = 'system';

               IndexInfo
        available_ranges
                 batches
             built_views
      compaction_history
                   local
                   paxos
             peer_events
                   peers
     prepared_statements
             range_xfers
                 repairs
          size_estimates
        sstable_activity
      transferred_ranges
 view_builds_in_progress
```

Thanks!

Comment: What Cassandra version are you using?

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson I am using DSE 6 / Cassandra 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version Apache Cassandra 3.0+, hints bypass the storage engine altoghether. Instead of storing the hints in a table, the files are stored locally on flat hint files much like commit logs.

More information on how this works can be found [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-coming-to-cassandra-in-3-0-improved-hint-storage-and-delivery).

Comment: If that is the case , not sure why DataStax have listed system.hints table in their DSE6 documentation :https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/useQuerySystem.html

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6230 - about hints redesign